# Firebase (FCM) registration token in Flutter

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification from *Java* Rest Api (using ***Firebase Admin sdk***) to my **Flutter application** and it seems it requires device token to send notification and I cannot find how to get that token. I am new to Flutter and android and may be missing any of the crucial step. Please help me if you can. Thanks.

Comment: @KENdi i will wan to know if you were able to get result on this, and if you do, i appreciate if you can assist me

Comment: Use rest API instead. https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-fcm-rest-api-7719925f2e3e

Comment: @abdulrehman I have followed your suggested link https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-fcm-rest-api-7719925f2e3e but notification does not have any sound. Could you please suggest me what is mean of 'default' sound? Can we change it with custom sound line 'blink.wav', 'alert.mp3'? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 84):

With `firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0`, you can directly get the token using

```dart
String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

or

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) {
  String? token = value;
});
```

Answer (score 56):

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
```

You can install packages from the command line:

with Flutter:

```
$ flutter packages get
```

Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
```

**Implementation:**

```
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();



@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();
}

void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();

  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
    print(token);
  });

  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on message $message');
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on resume $message');
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on launch $message');
    },
  );
}

void iOS_Permission() {
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
      .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings)
  {
    print("Settings registered: $settings");
  });
}
```

For more details step by information please refer [this](https://medium.com/@SebastianEngel/easy-push-notifications-with-flutter-and-firebase-cloud-messaging-d96084f5954f) link

Hope this helps you

Comment: It's working except when app is open do you have any suggestion to solve that in flutter

Comment: In order to show the notification even when the app is open or is running, you can use the flutter_local_notifications dependency.

Please check this git repo for more info https://github.com/nitishk72/firebase_messaging_flutter/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: I tried same as flutter doc of FirebaseMessaging. I even cloned the sample project from flutter's github.But i still get null with getToken.This is what I get in log:

W/FirebaseInstanceId( 4066):Token retrieval failed:SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval
W/FA ( 4066): Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id
E/FirebaseInstanceId( 4066): Failed to get FIS auth token
I/FA ( 4066): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 4066): getToken, error fetching instanceID:
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 4066): java.io.IOException: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Comment: Use Snackbar for notification when an app is open.

Comment: I recommend using overlay_support it has a fancy look and easy to implement 
https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_support

Comment: @rahul Rahul - could you please update your answer as per latest version of firebase fcm package? which will help me and other users. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

As you can the use the firebase Messaging Plugin to send the Notification. Through this code you can print the Token in Console.

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch called');
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume called');
    },
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage called');
    },
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('all');
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings(
    sound: true,
    badge: true,
    alert: true,
  ));
  _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
      .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
    print('Hello');
  });
  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
    print(token); // Print the Token in Console
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We need to add this package in pubspec.yaml file

```
firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
```

Perform packages get

Now import this in your code

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
```

Create instance of FirebaseMessaging

```
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
```

Now we just to add the function which I have created in the answer in the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523014/11887774

Answer (score -11):

I am not clear your question though. For FCM you have to extend FirebaseMessagingService.

Example:

```
class PNPFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
  override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
     // you can collect token from here
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this kotlin?

Comment: this is kotlin code not related to flutter it should be in dart