# How to return value on async function in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

This is my code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  token() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return "Lorem ipsum dolor";
  }
```

When I print, I got this message on debug console

```
Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

How I can get string of "lorem ipsum..." ? thank you so much

Comment: There's multiple ways, but seems you might want to read the docs https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures Note that SharedPreferences don't need to be asynchronous

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`token()` is async which means it returns `Future`. You can get the value like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

Future<String> token() async {
  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return "Lorem ipsum dolor";
}

token().then((value) {
  print(value);
});
```

But there is a better way to use SharedPreferences. Check docs [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-).

Answer (score 6):

In order to retrieve any value from async function we can look at the following example of returning String value from Async function. This function returns token from firebase as String.

```
Future<String> getUserToken() async {
 if (Platform.isIOS) checkforIosPermission();
 await _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
 return token;
 });
}
```

Fucntion to check for Ios permission

```
void checkforIosPermission() async{
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    await _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
}
```

Receiving the return value in function getToken

```
Future<void> getToken() async {
  tokenId = await getUserToken();
}

print("token " + tokenId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the function is **async** you need to use await for its response otherwise **Instance of 'Future'** will be output