# Firebase Messaging Push Notifications

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter

hi guys I'm trying to add push notifications to my flutter app. I want them to be sent to specific users an hour before an event happens the time of the event will be stored in firebase by the user. I have been doing my research and I think need to write these conditions in a node.js file? I also want to send another notification if an entry is added which is pretty straight forward. However I only would want to send it to the users in the same area as the user who added the entry. In my flutter app I use geohashes and haversine to query firebase for the user in the same area would I need to do the same in the node.js file. I am having trouble finding some good examples if this correct please direct me to some better resources if not please help me better understand what I should be doing. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's scope is wide but I will try to give you some kind of guideline for you to begin with.

First to set up an environment for firebase functions [follow this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), then there are [different triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) for firebase functions like **database write** calls a function to be executed when new data is written to the database.

In your case when you add an event inside your trigger write some code to get the users near that area and send notifications, and to send the notifications you will need to get the [token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54822356/6798995) of every user when they login to your app and save it somewhere else.

For firebase functions, you need to know basic Javascript/TypeScript and for that, [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) of Doug Stevenson is very helpful. I recommend finishing the tutorial first.

Comment: Thank you these resources should be very helpful. I did not expect exact answers to my questions this is what I was hoping for thank you.

Comment: I am really glad it helped, and you are welcome. If it solved your problem you may accept.