# Flutter How get token device with fcm on Android Mode

Tags: php, flutter

My project flutter 3.3 and fcm last version it error on product mode
It not get token device all android device
How config

Answer (score 0):

You'll need googleplay services in Android studio installed as well as emulator capable of running google APIs. then from root project directory run `flutter pub add firebase_messaging`. Also you will need to add this in the manifest file

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

Also this might be useful for dealing with the token: [Firebase (FCM) registration token in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821182/firebase-fcm-registration-token-in-flutter)